# Perform action when tapping on My Location in MapKit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

Is there a way to trigger code to execute when tapping on the "My Location" blue dot in MapKit?

[image]

I tried implementing `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {` but this doesn't get called when tapping the blue dot.  Instead, a pretty useless generic avatar annotation shows up as shown in the simulator screenshot above.  Can this behavior be customized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate function `mapView(viewForAnnotation)` and substitute your own view in the case where the annotation is the MKUserLocation. Now you are in charge of how the caption behaves.

Comment: Right, so then I would need to the-implement the look of the dot, the pulsing animation and color change when the location goes stale.  I can certainly do all that, but I was hoping do an easier way to capture a tap.